# How to get multiple elements by class name that are changing?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, dom-selection

Can anyone help me? 
I am trying to select multiple elements by class name.
Everything is good until somewhere in the middle of page *comments* text is not available, just reviewers name and product that has been reviewed.
How to set it to skip the element and move to the next row if it is not present for that particular row?

edited:
  So after suggestions, I tried using the below code but Console is saying
-**forEach is not a function**. I am running this on the following page:
https://www.etsy.com/shop/FamilyshirtsCo/reviews

```
var productRows = document.getElementsByClassName("div.flag-body pb-xs-0");
productRows.forEach(function(productRow){
var name = productRow.querySelector(".p.shop2-review-attribution");
var comments = productRow.querySelector(".p.prose break-word m-xs-0");
var product = productRow.querySelector(".flag-body hide-xs hide-sm");
var final = product[i].innerText +" | "+ price[i].innerText +" | "+ 
quantity[i].innerText;
console.log(final);
});
```

Comment: You are looking for childElement (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp)

Comment: Can you please share how does html looks like ?

Comment: Your question is too unclear. You would have to show HTML page content with/without - perhaps a couple of screenshots in Chrome Developer mode.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM8qN.png Check out the Xpaths and copy/paste them.

Answer (score 2):

getElementsByClassName returns all the element having the specified class, irrespective of its siblings or parent.
Here you can give the some class to the row's parent class:

So as the html structure will be as follows :

```
<div class="product-row">
    <div class="product">
        some product
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        some price
    </div>
    <div class="quantity">
        some quantity
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var productRows = document.getElementsByClassName("product-row");
productRows.forEach(function(productRow){
    var product = productRow.querySelector(".product");
    var price = productRow.querySelector(".price");
    var quantity = productRow.querySelector(".quantity");
    var order = product[i].innerText +" | "+ price[i].innerText +" | "+ quantity[i].innerText;
    console.log(order);
});
```

I hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks! So basically what I am trying to do is scrape these reviews from Etsy and so far unsuccessfully because for some reviews there are comments and for some, there are not. https://www.etsy.com/shop/FamilyshirtsCo/reviews

Comment: I tried using the above code but Console is saying forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Must be for loop not forEach. It is HTMLCollection not simple array.

```js
var productRows = document.getElementsByClassName("product-row");

for ( var x = 0; x < productRows.lenght; x++) {
 var product = productRows[x].querySelector(".product");
 var price = productRows[x].querySelector(".price");
 var quantity = productRows[x].querySelector(".quantity");
 var order = product[i].innerText + " | " +
   price[i].innerText + " | " +
   quantity[i].innerText;
   
 console.log(order);
};
```

```html
 <div class="product-row">
        <div class="product">
            some product
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            some price
        </div>
        <div class="quantity">
            some quantity
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should make clear, that in the HTML, the wrapper element is mandatory, and all the three product elements are also needed, or ohterwise you've to check the existense of `quantity` before retrieving its `innerText`. Also, `i` in your code suddenly pops up from nowhere ...